# JQuery - Window resize working on Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have the code below to show the Larger tracker on wider screens and the smaller tracker otherwise, but it is only working for me in Chrome and I can't get it to function in Firefox.

I'm not that familiar with JQuery, so I suspect it may just be a syntax error which Chrome is more forgiving of but I haven't been able to find the error when searching. Thanks for the help.

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
    var wi = $(window).width();

    if (wi <= 767){
        $('.LargerTracker').hide();
        $('.SmallerTracker').show();
        }
    else {
        $('.LargerTracker').show();
        $('.SmallerTracker').hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your logic is fine, you can see a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/ygxbtt6c/3/

Without seeing more code I can't tell for sure, but it's possible that you need to wait for the DOM ready event before binding your function to the window resize event.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // DOM is ready to be manipulated, put your code here
});
```

You can learn more about the ready event in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/%20jQuery%20documentation)